# PHP - Substring processing

Tags: php, substring

I have a set of strings that are in the format of `This.is.An.Example.YYYY.More.Data.Here` where `YYYY` is any valid year and I would like to get the string up until `YYYY` in the example so I would end up with a string that is `This.is.an.Example`.

Comment: `strstr('This.is.An.Example.YYYY.More.Data.Here', '.YYYY', TRUE);` and you're too broad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a simple regex, `\d{4}`.

```
$splitted = preg_split('~\d{4}~', 'This.is.An.Example.2015.More.Data');
echo $splitted[0];
```

Output:

> This.is.An.Example.

This will split one every 4 continuous single numbers (0-9). Since you only care about what is the first instance use the `0` index.

Sample: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/640224e9bda3e6cd5c3e012a1bb901dc1e6a34b4

Comment: Thanks, This is exactly what I was looking for, coming from a pure C background to PHP I expected there would be a simple elegent solution.

Answer (score 1):

Vague question, so I choose the simplest version ;-)

```
<?php
$in = 'This.is.An.Example.2015.More.Data.Here';
$out = strstr($in, '.2015', true);
echo $out;
```

prints `This.is.An.Example`
see http://docs.php.net/strstr

Comment: I edited the question to be less vauge but thanks for the response, given the criteria your solution was valid.